# Deleting contour httpproxy from Kubernetes namespace using java client

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, fabric8

I am working on the K8s implementation using kubernetes java client. I am looking for the solution to delete **Contour HTTPProxy** which are in invalid state. However I am not able to figure out how to do it with help of Java Client.

I am aware that we can delete the ingress using below code

`k8sClient.extensions().ingresses().withName("my-ingress").delete();`

Any help on how to delete Contour HTTPProxy object from K8s namespace using java client will be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contour HTTPProxy seems to be a [custom resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/). You can either use our [typed(required CustomResource POJOs)](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#customresource-typed-api) or [typeless API(CustomResource manipulation using raw maps)](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#customresource-typeless-api) for deleting HTTPProxy.

Here is an example of doing it using the typeless API(based on KubernetesClient v5.4.1):

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    CustomResourceDefinitionContext context = new CustomResourceDefinitionContext.Builder()
            .withKind("HTTPProxy")
            .withPlural("httpproxies")
            .withGroup("projectcontour.io")
            .withVersion("v1")
            .withScope("Namespaced")
            .build();

    boolean isDeleted = client.customResource(context).inNamespace("default").withName("root").delete();
    if (!isDeleted) {
        logger.warn("Unable to Delete HTTPProxy {} in {} namespace", "root", "default");
    }
    logger.info("HTTPProxy {} successfully deleted.", "root");
} catch (KubernetesClientException exception) {
    logger.error("Exception in interacting with Kubernetes API", exception);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan, really appreciate your time. Seems this is what I was looking for.